# Taking first element of a GroupedObservable with RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I'm pretty new to RxJava.

I'm trying to group elements by a given key and take the first value of each key.

For instance, group these names by their first letter and print the first one for each group:

```
Observable<String> names = Observable.just(
                             "John", "Steve", "Ruth",
                             "Sam", "Jane", "James");
```

Here's what I tried so far :

**1st try**:

```
names.groupBy(s -> s.charAt(0))
     .flatMap(grp -> grp.first())
     .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

*FAILED!*: all the names are printed.

**2nd try**:

```
names.groupBy(s -> s.charAt(0))
     .subscribe(grp -> grp
                         .first()
                         .subscribe(System.out::println));
```

*FAILED AGAIN!*: all the names are still printed...

I managed to get the expected result by reducing each GroupedObservable :

**1st try, with reduce**:

```
names.groupBy(s -> s.charAt(0))
     .flatMap(grp -> grp.reduce((a, b) -> a))
     .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

**2nd try, with reduce**:

```
names.groupBy(s -> s.charAt(0))
     .subscribe(grp -> grp
                         .reduce((a, b) -> a)
                         .subscribe(System.out::println));
```

But this solution is not ideal. In a real world situation, this would involve some expensive computation and the `reduce()` operator would take a lot longer to compute (computing all the values) than the `first()` operator (computing only 1 value by key).

Comment: What about `names.distinct(s -> s.charAt(0)).subscribe(/**/);`?

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati interresting way to solve the problem. It works well for the actual example. Unfortunately, it does not apply to my actual code which is more complex. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the property of `groupBy`: if a group gets cancelled (no longer observed), a new group with the same key may get started. Here `first` unsubscribes after the first element and the subsequent element with the same key recreates the group.

You can prevent this via some `publish` trickery:

```
Observable<String> names = Observable.just(
        "John", "Steve", "Ruth",
        "Sam", "Jane", "James");

names.groupBy(s -> s.charAt(0))
.flatMap(grp -> grp.publish(o -> o.first().concatWith(o.ignoreElements())))
.subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Here, I share the group and create a special output; a concatenation of the first element with the end of the whole group (ignoring elements).

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I find this a bit counterintuitive. I probably need to read the docs about this.