# get one element from each GroupedObservable in RxJava

Tags: group-by, rx-java

I'm struggling with groupBy in RxJava.
The problem is - I cant get only one element from each group.
For example i have a list of elements:

**SomeModel:**

```
class SomeModel {
   int importantField1;
   int mainData;
}
```

My **list of models** for example:

```
List<SomeModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add(new SomeModel(3, 1));
dataList.add(new SomeModel(3, 1));
dataList.add(new SomeModel(2, 1));
```

In my real project there is more complex data model. I added same models on purpose. It is matter for my project. 
Then I'm trying to take one element from group in this manner:

```
List<SomeModel> resultList = Observable.fromIterable(dataList)
.sorted((s1, s2) -> Long.compare(s2.importantField1, s1.importantField1))
.groupBy(s -> s.importantField1)
.firstElement()
// Some transformation to Observable. May be it is not elegant, but it is not a problem
.flatMapObservable(item -> item)
.groupBy(s -> s.mainData)
//Till this line I have all I need. But then I need to take only one element from each branch
.flatMap(groupedItem -> groupedItem.firstElement().toObservable())
.toList()
.blockingGet();
```

And of course it's not working. I still have two same elements in the resultList.

I cant add *.firstElement()*, after last *.flatMap* operator, because there could be situations when after last *.groupBy* may be more then one branch.
I need only one element from **each branch**.

I've tryed this way:

```
.flatMap(groupedItem -> groupedItem.publish(item -> item.firstElement().concatWith(item.singleElement()).toObservable())
```

no effect. This sample of code I took from this post: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38149222/17953936)
There author suggests this :

```
.flatMap(grp -> grp.publish(o -> o.first().concatWith(o.ignoreElements())))
```

but even if I remove last two rows of my code:

```
.toList()
.blockingGet();
```

And change *resultList* to *Disposable disposable* suggested option not working because of error:

```
.concatWith(o.ignoreElements()) - concatWith not taking Completable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some method signatures changed with 3.x since [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38149222/61158) so you'll need these:

- `first` -> `firstElement`
- `firstElement` returns `Maybe` which is no good inside `publish`, plus there is no `Maybe.concatWith(CompletableSource)`, thus the need to convert to `Observable`.

```java
.flatMap(grp -> 
    grp.publish(o ->
        o.firstElement()
         .toObservable()
         .concatWith(o.ignoreElements())
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't work for me.
I found solution in other way.